# postgres-decoderbufs-master -- centos7

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, debezium

I am trying to CDC by debezium protobuf of postgres 9.6 and as per instruction i have downloaded source from git and trying to make then it have some problem and try to find out the solution on satckoverflow and other sites also then for ubuntu os many solution are available but for centosh 7 no solution found

The following error is coming when i fired make command

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:62: /usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Package libprotobuf-c was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libprotobuf-c.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libprotobuf-c' found
/usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:105: /src/Makefile.shlib: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/src/Makefile.shlib'.  Stop.
```

if any help it will very useful for my project.

Answer (score 1):

You need a protobuf-c-devel package installed. Also there is a problem with version. Check if your system has the correct version otherwise you'd need to install it from 3rd part RPM repository - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/debezium/v0s3tacOXeA/gVrdQAR2AgAJ;context-place=forum/debezium